# Rotate image counterclockwise with JQueryRotate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to rotate an image 180 degrees counterclockwise every time the user click's the image's parent element. I'm using JQueryRotate v2.3.

My code:

```
$('.material').click(function () {              
    var thisPic = $(this).find('.fanpic');
    thisPic.rotate({ animateTo: -180 });;
});
```

This works at first, but the image starts spinning clockwise with the second click onward. How can I fix this so the image always spins counterclockwise?

Comment: You should really look at JQueryRotate's examples next time... [Example #5](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples#Example_5), Here they have a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/ This question isn't worth answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping the rotate value at somewhere for example in the parent element:

```
$('.material').click(function () {
    if(!this.animateTo) this.animateTo = 0;
    this.animateTo = this.animateTo + -180;
    var thisPic = $(this).find('.fanpic');
    thisPic.rotate({ animateTo: this.animateTo });;
});
```

Try this <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RwEme/8401/)</kbd>

Hope this helps,

Comment: Your fiddle works great, but unfortunately it assumes the graphic I'm rotating is the object returning the click event. I'll edit my post with what how I'm applying your code and what happens.

Comment: A thousand pardons -- I misread your code and that's why it wasn't working for me at first. It works as written, and I need to RTFC. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can keep a variable with the angle.

```
var angle = -180;
$('.material').click(function () {              
    var thisPic = $(this).find('.fanpic');
    thisPic.rotate({ animateTo: angle });
    angle -= 180;
});
```

Comment: Wrong logic. Once you do `angle -= -180`, it becomes `+180`. So you would have to do `angle -= 180` or `angle = angle - 180`